# Visual Studio 2010 Add-In Problem

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0

I just created a Assembly and a Visual Studio Add-In like this:

**At first, the assembly**

- File => New Project
- New Class Library

After i have changed the content of the "Class1.cs" file to

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    public class Class1
    {
        public void Test()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Wohooo!");
        }
    }
}
```

**And now, the Add-In**

- File => New Project
- Visual Studio Add-In
- Clicking through the Wizard

After i have changed the content of the "Connect.cs" file to:

```
public class Connect : IDTExtensibility2, IDTCommandTarget
{
...
    public void OnConnection(object application, ext_ConnectMode connectMode, object addInInst, ref Array custom)
    {
    // Adding a button to thet tools menu
// i can provide the source if needed
    }           

    public void QueryStatus(string commandName, vsCommandStatusTextWanted neededText, ref vsCommandStatus status, ref object commandText)
    {
        if (neededText == vsCommandStatusTextWanted.vsCommandStatusTextWantedNone)
        {
            status = (vsCommandStatus)vsCommandStatus.vsCommandStatusSupported |
                     vsCommandStatus.vsCommandStatusEnabled;
        }
    }
```

**If i call the new class from the Exec Method, nothing happens. (No debug break point get fired)**

```
    public void Exec(string CmdName, vsCommandExecOption ExecuteOption, ref object VariantIn, ref object VariantOut, ref bool Handled)
    {
        Action action = GetAction(CmdName);

        if (CmdName == "MyAddin2.Connect.SampleAddin2")
        {
            new ClassLibrary1.Class1().Test();             
            Console.WriteLine("");
        }

        Handled = true;
    }
```

**if not, it works!**

```
    public void Exec(string CmdName, vsCommandExecOption ExecuteOption, ref object VariantIn, ref object VariantOut, ref bool Handled)
    {
        Action action = GetAction(CmdName);

        if (CmdName == "MyAddin2.Connect.SampleAddin2")
        {
            // new ClassLibrary1.Class1().Test();             
            Console.WriteLine("");
        }

        Handled = true;
    }
```

But why ? What is the problem ?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

Check Assembly tag in "For - Testing" addin file.
Check the folder it points to and if that folder contains 'ClassLibrary1.dll'. I had a similar (or identical) problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7243773/).